# tikzstyle introduces no shape known error

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Quite strangely,
`\node (S) at (0,0) [circle, fill, label={270:Source $S$}]{};
\draw [blue, ->] (S) -- node[label={$\vec v$}] {} (1,0.5) -- (2,1);`

functions properly and gives me what I want, but

`\tikzstyle{dots} = {circle, fill}
\node (S) at (0,0) [dots, label={270:Source $S$}]{};
\draw [blue, ->] (S) -- node[label={$\vec v$}] {} (1,0.5) -- (2,1);`

leads to a "no shape named S" error. What's going on ? Is there some expected behaviour from `tikzstyle` I should know about ?

Edit: Apparently, the mere usage of `tikzstyle` causes the error, even if I don't use the dots style I made in the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the old and deprecated `\tikzstyle` with `\tikzset` syntax. Use either

```
\tikzstyle{dots}=[circle,fill]
```

or better

```
\tikzset{dots/.style={circle,fill}}
```

Comment: I didn't even think about that... Thanks a bunch !